# How to know if form field allows multiple values?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to export `forms` metadata to `SQL Server`.  I am having a hard time trying to figure out if a field allows multiple values, is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors have you received? Do you have code you can post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most items within Lotus Notes documents can support multiple values.  The fields on a form can be set to allow / disallow multiple entries but the underlying NotesItem within the NotesDocument object can usually support multiple values.

Here is some documentation on this:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_VALUES_PROPERTY.html

The rich text item doesn't support multiple values, but for text, number and date types you have to assume that there may be multiple values there.

Comment: You could to a DXL export of the design and parse the XML for the relevant info. But that doesn't stop a developer from adding multivalues anyway. So you basically have to check the values you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't be sure. Even if the field has option "Allow multiple values" switched off anyway I can set multivalued value into the field in background. When you export you need scan all documents and find out whether a field contains multivalued values or not.